# Problem activating MAF add-in with custom AppDomain

Tags: .net, appdomain, sandbox, maf

I am trying to use the overload of MAF's `AddInToken.Activate()` method that accepts an `AppDomain`, so that I can pass an application domain created by my client application.

When the passed `AppDomain` is configured with unrestricted permissions it works fine, but if I reduce the permission set (for example, by using the Internet sandbox permission set) MAF throws a `SecurityException` when performing the reflection necessary to discover its add-ins. Since the MAF assemblies are installed in the GAC, shouldn't they be fully trusted?

I know that MAF offers other method overloads that will create an `AppDomain` for me and allow me to specify the permission set assigned it, but I can't use this approach in my app, because I need to be able to specify the list of my own strong-named assemblies that will be given full trust.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Tim